# How to make a transparent image in PHP

Tags: php

I want to remove a background from my image:

[image]

My script can be found [here](http://developers.sabayload.com/php/imagecopymerge.php):

```html
<?php

 //header('Content-type:jpeg');

 // Create image instances

 $dest = imagecreatefromjpeg('images/bg.jpg');

 $src = imagecreatefrompng('images/Title.png');

 imagealphablending($src, false);

 imagesavealpha($src, true);

 // Copy and merge

 imagecopymerge($dest, $src, 0, 300, 0, 0, 700, 150, 75);

 // Output and free from memory

 imagejpeg($dest,'images/print/imagecopymerge.jpg');

 imagedestroy($dest);

 imagedestroy($src);

?>

<img src="images/print/imagecopymerge.jpg">
```

Can anyone help me accomplish this?

Comment: Use photoshop and save it as a `png`

Comment: Your image doesn't appear to be 'transparent'; you appear to be trying to remove a substantial block of colour. Sure, you can set opacity on `imagecreatefrompng`, but I'd recommend using an external application like PhotoShop for actual **manipulation** of the image.

Comment: Is there any reason why you choose to manage images in backend instead of css and js?

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to make a png image and use that with transparency (Could use Paint.net free :) or Photoshop/Illustrator Paid :(. This will give you more time to work on other things that might you might be finding hard to work out.